# Keyup function is not transferring data in the lower div

Tags: javascript, jquery

keeping it simple and short, this is my code and I want to have the text content from the text input field to be shown in another div(showcontent)..although no jQuery error is flagging in my firebug..but still it is not showing content in the lower div, let me know what I am doing wrong ?

Also let me know the correct function for this type of functionality if `keyup` is not appropriate for handling this?

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="usertext" placeholder="Enter text" id="usertext" />
</form>

<div id="showcontent"></div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#usertext').keyup(function(){
        var mytext = jQuery('#usertext').text();
        jQuery('#showcontent').html(mytext);
    });
});
</script>
```

I tried `jQuery('#usertext').on('keyup',function(){...});`  but no help :(

Comment: change var mytext = jQuery('#usertext').text() to var mytext = jQuery('#usertext').val();

Comment: @AkhilSekharan thx it works ..paste it as an answer and I will approve it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is proble in reading text from `input box`

use this

```
var mytext = jQuery('#usertext').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

if u are using jquery to get the value of a textbox then u should always use val() method and if u want to get the text inside a  span or a div u should use text() method..so u should write your code int the following way

```
$('#usertext').keyup(function(){
//B.T.W $(this) refers to the current element ie the textbox
       $('#showcontent').text($(this).val());
});
```